# Clarifying EC2's system log following crash

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, logging

We've recently had an issue with an EC2 instance that bought down our mySQL service.

I've checked the system log (**AWS Console: Action > Instance Settings > Get System Log**)

However the output isn't self explanatory:

For instance there are hundreds of lines along the following:

```
[7240052.632109] [15542]    48 15542   100366     1980     190       3        0             0 httpd
```

...until the systems runs out of memory:

```
[7240052.636809] Out of memory: Kill process 15239 (httpd) score 10 or sacrifice child
```

Could anyone explain what the first line means? It's columns aren't explained anywhere I can locate. I'm assuming column 6 and 7 are memory related as I can see them dropping before the crash.

Comment: Log in to the system and read the actual log.  It should be in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages.  *"until the systems runs out of memory"*  Not really "until." That was earlier.  All of this information is here **because** the system ran out of memory.  You're seeing part of a dump of data about the running processes at the time the incident occurred.